# Why Visual Studio Team Services Build always failed with TeamFoundationServiceException

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I setup a website on Azure and link to a VS Team Services Git repository. When I make a new commit & push new code to the remote repository, a new build will be executed but it's always failed with below message.

> Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (type TeamFoundationServiceException)
>   Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ConnectedServicesWebService.GetConnectedService(String name, String teamProject)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.DeploymentService.GetDeploymentEnvironment(String name, String teamProject)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
>
> Inner Exception Details:
>
> Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (type SoapException)SoapException Details: 
>   Exception Stack Trace:

If I publish the same code to github and linked again to Azure, CD works fine, new changes will be published. I am not sure what was wrong there, can anyone please help? Any idea would be appreciated!